# What's a good P to use in ElGamal key generation?

Tags: encryption, elgamal-encryption

I need to generate a 1024 bit ElGamal key on Android, and key generation takes forever (~10 minutes on a Galaxy Nexus), I suspect because it take so long to generate a safe prime.

Is it dangerous for me to use the same safe prime p for all devices using my app?

Where can I find a list of 1024 bit and 2048 bit safe prime numbers?

I'm using it for encryption, and I'm wary about hard-coding a P/G because of the [this attack.](ftp://ftp.inf.ethz.ch/pub/crypto/publications/Bleich96.pdf) I know it says only for signatures, but I'm still wary of introducing weakness because I am by no means an experienced cryptographer. The IETF has a list of good Ps to use, but they advocate using G=2, as seen [here](https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-ietf-ipsec-ike-modp-groups-04.txt).

Comment: Any reason why you want to use ElGamal over Diffie-Hellman, DSA or Schnorr signatures? Are you talking about ElGamal encryption or ElGamal signatures?

Comment: What's wrong with G=2?  If you can decrypt ElGamal encrypted messages with base 2, you can decrypt ElGamal encrypted messages with any base (assuming you use a safe prime; one with (p-1)/2 prime).

Answer (score 1):

With most finite field crypto using a standard group is no problem. I think ElGamal encryption doesn't have any specific requirements for group or generator that plain Diffie-Hellman doesn't have.

So you could look into [RFC 2409  Internet Key Exchange](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2409) or [RFC 5114  Additional Diffie-Hellman Groups for Use with IETF Standards](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5114) for groups.

AFAIK ElGamal signatures have some additional requirements for the generator, so the above groups are probably a bad idea. But I wouldn't use ElGamal signatures in the first place, preferring DSA or Schnorr.